# ActiveMQ with stomp calling function inside a website

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a website on my local host using WAMP and PHP. When I enter the website it sends a message to the MQserver using stomp, since I'm really new using ActiveMQ I'm stuck on the following. I want the mqServer that sends that message to a different website to fire off a function on that website without me having to go directly to that website. I have taken a look at apache camel but that is for JMS and I don't exactly know what that is either or if I can use it.